# Any way to install a lib on a project and use it globally on any file without needing to require it all the time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is as follows:

I have a library and would like to know if it is possible to implement something in it, that the moment I install it to some node project, I can simply call the main function, without needing to import it into the X file. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is `webpack.ProvidePlugin` [webpack.ProvidePlugin Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#root)

Comment: Thanks, this helps in some cases. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, the idea would be to create a method that works just like the case with require or others.